# Does lim sum equal sum lim hold?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, power-series

Let $$F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)  $$ where $$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^3}{n^4+x^4}.$$
Does  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$$  hold?

Termwisely taking limit  gives  the limit of RHS equals to $0$. LHS is where I'm stuck. I could not find any geometric or telescoping structure in the sum.

Comment: I think it depends on the type of continuity, but not sure

Comment: how about direct proof ? not using any theorem about uniform convergence?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added later: You have shown that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for each $n.$ We also have, for each $m\in \mathbb N,$ $f_m(m) = 1/2.$ It follows that $F(m) > f_m(m) = 1/2.$ Thus $F$ fails to have limit $0$ at $\infty.$ Hence

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{x\to \infty}f_n(x)\,\,\text { fails }.$$

---

Hint: $F(m) > f_m(m)$ for all $m \in \mathbb N.$

Comment: why is this helpful?

Comment: Did you compute $f_m(m)?$